# About Qt MessageBox::warning() overloading

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, overloading

```
QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("Error"),
                             tr("File existed"));
```

I use QtCreator for MSVS2012,Win7. "this" points to a class that public inherited from QWizard class, the compiler output is

> error C2665: “QMessageBox::warning”: 4 个重载中没有一个可以转换所有参数类型
>           d:\qt\qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2012_64\include\qtwidgets\qmessagebox.h(197): 可能是“QMessageBox::StandardButton QMessageBox::warning(QWidget *,const QString &,const QString &,QMessageBox::StandardButtons,QMessageBox::StandardButton)”
>           尝试匹配参数列表“(const newWizard *const , QString, QString)”时

it means none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types.
Anyone can give me some help?

Comment: Just to get this clear, is the `个重载中没有一个可以转换所有参数类型` a custom error message you created yourself in the source? Or (showing my total ignorance about Qt here) are you using a localised version of Qt?

Comment: @MrLister: he's using a localized version of Windows it seems.

Comment: It looks like 'this' is a pointer to a const QWidget, while it requires a non-const object.

Comment: @MrLister"4个重载中没有一个可以转换所有参数类型"I'm a chinese. it means none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: @JRG: And do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: @Marz: If you want to use "this" as parent, you must call warning()in a non-const method.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I have find the key that i use warning() in "int nextId() const". Thank you for your advice, it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `this` with `0` and it should work.

Basically, the dialog box doesn't need a parent.  It can stand alone and not have a problem.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

And like the comments to your question said, you can't call the warning in a `const` method either.

Another option is that you could get rid of the `const`'ness of your `newWizard()` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought the dialog box must have a parent!!Thank you.

Comment: @Marz: Technically dialog must not have a parent, but its good practice to give every window one, as not assigning parent can cause issues with window stacking (modal message boxes coming up in the background behind the disabled main window; nasty!). That's especially evil on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast `this` to `QWidget *` 
And I agree with @phyatt, you can set parent = 0. Mean that your warning has no parent and it's child of desktop.

E.g:

```
QMessageBox::warning((QWidget *)this,tr("Error"),
                             tr("File existed"));
QMessageBox::warning(0,tr("Error"),
                             tr("File existed"));
```

Comment: Your advice is also useful.In fact I use  const_cast<QWizard *>  to solve this problem.

Comment: Yup, const_cast is better :)